# (Python) Creating a column in a df based on values from multiple other columns

Tags: python, string

I have the following `df`...

```
activity     dependents

a            null
b            a
c            ab
d            ab
e            ad
f            d
g            abcf
```

... where the `dependents` are prerequisites for the activities. Example: `activity` `a` has no prerequisites. The prerequisite for for `activity` `b` is `activity` `a`. The prerequisites for `activity` `c` are `activity` `a` & `b`. (And so on...)

I want to create the column `sequels` that shows which `activity(s)` are waiting on the current `activity` before it can begin.
The desired output would look like...

```
activity     dependents     sequels

a            null           bcdeg
b            a              cdg
c            ab             g
d            ab             efg
e            ad             g
f            d              g
g            abcf           null
```

As `g` is the final `activity` there are no follow-on tasks and thus, blank/ null.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: you can take a look at topological sort order 
https://leetcode.com/problems/course-schedule-ii/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
d = {'activity': ['a', 'b' ,'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'],
    'dependents': ['', 'a', 'ab', 'ab', 'ad', 'd', 'abcf']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

activity_list= list(df["activity"])
sequels = ["" for i in activity_list]
#adding dependents
for (i,activity) in enumerate(activity_list):
    for index,data in df.iterrows():
        if activity in data["dependents"]:
            sequels[i]+=(data["activity"])
#adding 'g' at the end when it's not there
for (i,s) in enumerate(sequels[:-1]):
    if activity_list[-1] not in s:
        sequels[i]+=activity_list[-1]

df["sequels"]=sequels
```

I'm not sure if it's what you're looking for but the output df looks like the one you showed us

Answer (score 0):

Probably there is someone out there who can give you a oneliner for this, but here's my best shot:

```
d = {'activity': ['a', 'b' ,'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'],
    'dependents': ['', 'a', 'ab', 'ab', 'ad', 'd', 'abcf']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

# Create dictionary where every key is an activity
activity_dict = {act: '' for act in df['activity'].drop_duplicates()}

# Fill the activity dictionary with the correct sequels
def fill_dict(act, dependents):
    for dep in dependents:
        activity_dict[dep] += act

# Apply the fill_dict function using the dataframe
df.apply(lambda x: fill_dict(x['activity'], x['dependents']), axis=1)

# Translate dictionary into a column of the dataframe
df['sequels'] = df['activity'].apply(lambda x: activity_dict[x])
```

In your example it wasn't necessary, but maybe you need to get rid of duplicate sequels in the dictionary first before putting it back in the dataframe.